# How to properly create an enum conforming to ErrorType

Tags: ios, error-handling, enums, swift2

I am using Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7.
Following the guide I've defined an enum for my custom error type:

```
enum MyCustomError: ErrorType {
    case Error1(retries: Int)
    case Error2
    case Error3(message: NSString)
}
```

But I get the following errors:

1. `Raw type 'ErrorType' is not convertible from any literal`
2. `Type 'MyCustomError' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'`

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get an error: http://swiftstub.com/691955269/?v=beta
Where is the error occuring?

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxD3TTKMuRC06Oj3yxSQxf6RFdxAyqlSXc) your errors, it works.

Comment: Launching swift from the Terminal, I can't reproduce the errors.
But In Xcode I have these errors

Comment: This enum is in a swift file where i have all the constants and enums. Any suggestions to solve this issue?